# Side affects of deleting JAR during execution

Tags: java

Lets say I start an application which has a JAR on its classpath: `java -cp /path/to/myapp.jar com.my.Clazz`

I then delete the JAR `/path/to/myapp.jar`. What if any, are the side affects to the running process?

Will it continue to run unhindered? Will it run and eventually fail? I have done my own "test" and it appears to continue to run but I am sure this is not conclusive.

Comment: btw why are you doing this?

Comment: I accidentally deleted a JAR whilst a process was running which prompted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes are loaded as they are needed, so if you load one, and later it needs another, it will need the jar